# What is the correct way of dealing with a user who argues in comments about question quality?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563871/microsoft-access-database-assignment) <sup>(10k+ only - OP finally deleted it)</sup>, and read some of the comments (just read a few - you don't need to read them all, we've literally gone around in circles). Essentially the question was a homework assignment with the whole question consisting of a copy & paste from his teacher.

I wrote a fairly concise comment asking the OP to try something, come back when he was stuck, and post up a *specific* question.

The OP decides to berate me, telling me I'm wasting his time, and that the reason for all of the downvotes is because of all of our back-and-forth in the comments.

There were about 15 messages or so exchanged, and I kept on-point and matter-of-fact, even after he insults my intelligence and development skills.

I'm 99% sure I'm in the right here, and 5 other downvoters seem to agree.

I already flagged the question before I made my first comment.

I know I'm not perfect, so that's why I'm asking this question: How would you have handled this particular situation?

Comment: You might want to make your question here more descriptive. Should the post ever disappear then we have no clue what you're talking about. (And there we go....)

Comment: @Bart I've updated my question but I think it's all in vain now, with  the comment thread lost. This question now really doesn't make a lot of sense... "you'd have to have been there".

Comment: Simple answer: If you can vote to close, vote. If you can flag, flag. And then walk away. Long exchanges don't bring you anything.

Comment: @Bart Are 10k+ users able to see voluntarily deleted questions?

Comment: Yes, they will be able to see it.

Comment: I wouldn't have responded a second time. You explained your down-vote, move on and don't re-engage unless asked how to improve the question

Comment: @Danny, yes, we can see the question and its comments. For what it's worth, I believe you should have let go after `My reply was not an attempt to open a bashing session, I am simply just looking for guidance from people whom know this type of work inside and out`, and let downvotes and close votes do the job.

Comment: And for all those who can't see it: There was no question there. A copy-paste of a homework assignment with zero-effort. NARQ, too localized, take your pick.

Comment: Ok, so basically don't bother responding and getting into extended discussions... it was more the provocation that prompted the continued replies, I guess. Thanks for that guys, I'm always looking to improve, so it's certainly helpful. If someone wants to write an answer, we can close this off.

Comment: To add to my comment above your comments seem to have gone over the invisible line as you got more frustrated with the user not seeing your point. This doesn't happen when you just stop engaging completely.

Comment: The thing is, it was as if the OP didn't *understand* what I was saying. It just wasn't getting through to him, no matter how I worded it. I take all of your comments in steed though! Definitely won't bother wasting my time in the future... cheers guys.

Comment: downvote vote to close and leave it at that.  Whether or not the op is convinced that his question is a problem question isn't that important

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This situation is a simple one. The OP posted a homework description and that's it. No effort, and going to be closed in any case. Downvote, flag or vote to close as you see fit.

You could leave one comment, particularly for new users, kindly explaining how it's not a good question for the site. But if they then come back to start a discussion with you on how you're wrong, walk away. By that point you've done all you could, and if they are not interested in improving the post, there's no point to continue any conversation.

Should the comments get out of hand, flag those as well, but don't feed them with any additional comments. Move on. You have (no doubt) better things to do with your time.

Comment: 2 days in a row, 2 great answers on my MSO questions - thanks a lot Bart!!